# Exception Error in Tkinter callback: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'type'

Tags: python, tkinter

Not very experienced in python yet, and also trying to learn GUI in this platform. Have a form I'm trying to run a monte carlo simulation when pressing a button on the form. Running the code that uses the line marked as #line 7, I get the callback error. When replacing line 7 with line 8, then the call back error occurs in line #19. When running this same code outside of Tkinter, no error occurs. What is causing this error?  The relevant code is as follows:

```
def plot_results(df):
    """Plot confidence intervals, 
    """
    y = df.index
    xmin = df['eta_LCI']
    xmax = df['eta_UCI']
    flag = ((Scale < simulated['eta_LCI']) | (Scale > simulated['eta_UCI']))    #line 7
    # flag = np.logical_or((Shape < df['beta_LCI']), (Shape > df['beta_UCI']))  #line 8
    lincolor = ['r' if i else 'tab:gray' for i in flag]
    linwid = [0.5 if i else 0.2 for i in flag]

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16,6))
    #Summary Plot for eta
    ax1.set_xlabel('Interval Range')
    #ax1.set_xlim(right=3*Scale)

    ax1.set_ylabel('Simulation')
    ax1.set_title(r'{:5.1f}% Two-Sided Confidence Interval for $\eta$'.format((1 - 0.05) * 100))
    ax1.axvline(Scale, color='b')  # line 19
    ax1.hlines(y, xmin, xmax, color=lincolor, linewidth=linwid)
    ax1.text(df['eta_LCI'].min(), 0, s = 'Confidence Prop.: {:5.4f}'.format(1 - sum(flag) / MC))

    #summary plot for beta
    y = df.index
    xmin = df['beta_LCI']
    xmax = df['beta_UCI']
    flag = np.logical_or((Shape < df['beta_LCI']), (Shape > df['beta_UCI']))
    lincolor = ['r' if i else 'k' for i in flag]
    linwid = [0.7 if i else 0.2 for i in flag]

    ax2.set_xlabel('Interval Range')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Simulation')
    ax2.set_title(r'{:5.1f}% Two-Sided Confidence Interval for $\beta$'.format((1 - 0.05) * 100))
    ax2.axvline(Shape, color='b')
    ax2.hlines(y, xmin, xmax, color=lincolor, linewidth=linwid)
    ax2.text(df['beta_LCI'].min(), 0, s = 'Confidence Prop.: {:5.4f}'.format(1 - sum(flag) / MC))

    return fig
```

Comment: What's `Scale`?  is it a `float` or a type?

Comment: Scale is a float.

Comment: I even made explicit the float but still got the message.

Comment: We’d need to see where `Scale` and `simulated` are defined.  One of those things isn’t the type it should be.

Comment: I did some diagnostic on the script. As I was learning GUI, I had placed an 'import tkinter' statement after having defined the Scale and Shape variables (intended to be global). The problem disappeared after placing the 'import tkinter' before defining Scale and Shape. Not sure if this is related to the use of the 'reliability' library. The simulated df stores the results of parameter estimation of monte carlo samples using this library. I haven't tried any other way to see if the error can be replicated. Making sure import is at the top works for now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).